# "Get / make something + adjective"

Tags: sentence-construction, spoken-english

As a learner I always use:

**Make something adjective,** as in,

> I need to **make it clean.**

But today I saw:

> You need to rub hard to **get it clean.**

Are they both valid to a native speaker?

Answer (score 4):

The choices you provided are both valid options with this adjective; **"get it clean"** is generally more casual and common, but **"make it clean"** is natural enough that nobody would notice either way.

However, **"get"** doesn't work in all situations. For example, you can **"get something clean,"** **"safe,"** or **"wet"** but you cannot **"get something difficult,"** **"blue,"** or **rough."** I've been trying to figure out the exact pattern for about an hour now without success, and at this point I no longer think there is one. So, welcome to another area in which English has strange exceptions for no logical reason.

Luckily, in the *very specific* context of "verb-noun-adjective," **make** is acceptable in 99% of cases. The only exception I can think of is that you can **get someone married**, but you *cannot* **make someone married**. Admittedly for adjectives which normally use **get** (particularly **wet**), **make** does sound somewhat stilted, but it's grammatically correct and thus perfectly valid. I wouldn't worry about it; by the time you reach the point it becomes a concern, you'll probably have already memorized the various rules just by listening.

*This isn't important whatsoever*, but for the sake of being thorough, **"finally got"** can technically be used with any adjective. For example, I would never say **"I got it blue,"** but if I managed to make it blue after several hours of trying I *could* say **I finally got it blue!"** However, this is extremely informal, sounds somewhat uncultured, and **"I finally made it blue"** is still perfectly acceptable.